# Obtain the value of a checkbox element in a form through a POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to make a simple to-do app using JavaScript (Node.js,Express.js and ejs for templating). I've used a form to POST the value of an input textbox, and each time the "submit" button is pressed, a JS object with the task text and an ID is appended to an array "allTasks".

However, I want to be able to cross out a list item using a checkbox. I was able to do it using CSS, but the checkbox is cleared after every "submit" since the list is generated using a *for* *loop* for the elements in the "tasksList" array. This is how it currently works:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12R3o.gif)

This is the relevant section in my index.ejs file:

```html
<form action="/submit" method="POST">
    <label for="item">New item...</label>
    <input type="text" id="task" name="task" required />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
    
<form action="/checked" method="POST">
    
    <% for(i=0; i<locals.tasksList.length; i++) {%>
    
    <li> 
        <input type="checkbox">
        <label for="<%= locals.taskId %>"> <%=  (locals.tasksList[i]["newTask"])%> </label>
    </li>
    
    <%}%>
    
</form>
```

And this is the relevant section in my index.js file:

```js
var allTasks = [];

app.post("/submit", (req, res) => {
  var newTask = req.body["task"];
  var idNumber = allTasks.length;
  allTasks.push({ idNumber, newTask });
  res.render(__dirname + "/views/index.ejs", {
    tasksList: allTasks,
    taskId: idNumber,
  });
});

app.post("/checked", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

One way to solve this could be to store the elements that have been checked in an array in the index.js file, similar to the allTasks array. I tried to get the value of the checkbox (ticked/or not) by using console log, but that results in an empty object being printed to the console. A solution to this problem or any better solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: Input elements need a `name` attribute, to become candidates for inclusion in the form submission data set. Your checkboxes don't have one. And they don't have any `value` either, so even if they were checked, you would only receive the default value `on`.

Comment: And a `for` attribute on a label needs to refer to the ID of an input element.

Comment: @CBroe I tried adding a name and a value like so: 
`name="check" value="<%=(locals.tasksList[i]["newTask"])%>"`, however it still does not seem to be posting any value on clicking the checkbox. As for the _for_ attribute of the label, it points to the ID of the checkbox element.

Comment: _"however it still does not seem to be posting any value on clicking the checkbox"_ - clicking on a checkbox, does not submit a form. You will need to add a submit button, of some JavaScript to automatically submit the form (but the latter would probably make rather little sense, because then you could only click one checkbox at a time.) _"As for the for attribute of the label, it points to the ID of the checkbox element."_ - and that ID was set were exactly, in `<input type="checkbox">` ...?

Comment: Are you expecting the body of the request to be JSON on the `/checked` endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preselect checkboxes when recovering the data you need to compare "value" with the "checked" condition.
You also need to add a common name.